# Using css lib, it doesnot generate .css.res file

Tags: codenameone

1.copied  cn1css-ant-task.jar file in lib and refresh lib

2.code change in build.xml

```
<taskdef name="compileCSS"
        classname="com.codename1.ui.css.CN1CSSCompileTask"
        classpath="lib/cn1css-ant-task.jar"/>

    <target name="compile-css">
        <compileCSS/>
    </target>
 <target name="-pre-compile" depends="compile-css">
```

3.kept roundedBorder.css file inside theme folder

But it doesnot generate roundedBorder.css.res file. How can I do that? 
One more thing while refreshing the lib, it gives error

```
D:\gitCodenameone\0Lenovo\Lenovo\build.xml:18: taskdef class com.codename1.build.client.InitOfflineBuilder cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[D:\gitCodenameone\0Lenovo\Lenovo\CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar]
```

If I delete
"taskdef name="initOfflineBuilder" classname="com.codename1.build.client.InitOfflineBuilder" classpath="CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar"
from build.xml, the project runs in simulator but will give error while building the apk , however still doesnot generate css.res file.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause but generally I'd avoid directory names with spaces as they tend to be "flaky"

Comment: Removing space in the directory doesnt solve the problem. However I am most interested in why doesn't it generate css.res file as it should have been automatically generated as mentioned in cn1 css blog, right? Or should I do anything else to generate that file?

Comment: Do you still get those build errors?  Or is it building without error and still not generating the .res file?

Comment: I tried in my other laptop where I had updated the cn1 few days ago & it doesnot gives build error but still not generating .css.res file. Will the file generates automatically while running project in simulator?

Comment: Yes.  It should automatically generate the .res file.  Note:  The .res file will be generated in the src directory, not the css directory.   Also are you using Netbeans, Eclipse, or IntelliJ.  Eclipse has some additional install steps.

Comment: I'm using netbeans

Comment: If there are no errors reported and it's not generating the file, then likely it's not even running the CSS step.  Can you paste your entire build.xml into a gist so I can take a look?